# Добавление записи в таблицу через Entity добавляет запись в связанную таблицу

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Есть класс

```
public class DbItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Products Product { get; set; }
}
```

где класс **Products** - это таблица в БД

При добавлении новой **DbItem** в БД , происходит попытка добавления **Products** в соответствующую таблицу в БД. Но добавления не просходит и выскакивает ошибка, что элемент с таким ключом уже существует.

Мне нужно добавить новый элемент только в таблицу **DbItem**

Сам `Products Product` беру из БД как `AsNoTracking()`

Как обновлять и добавлять элемента только в таблицу **DbItem** ?

Class Products

```
[Table("Products")]
public class Products
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите название")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Не выбрана категория")]
    public int Category { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

Update

```
var product = _context.Product.AsNoTracking().Where(x=>x.ProductId == Id).FirstOrDefault();

var dbitem = new Dbitem{Id = 1, Product = product};
_context.Dbitem.Add(dbitem);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: `Products` - множественное число. Меж тем у вас это название класса/сущности, так? Оно должно быть в единственном числе. И покажите его определение.

Comment: Alexander Petrov да это сущность, добавил определение

Comment: `new Dbitem{Id = 1` - не делайте так. Айдишники не для человека, они для машины. Вас не должно интересовать, какие значения там назначаются движком СУБД. Вы никогда даже не должны видеть эти значения. / Почему большинство начинающих так упорно цепляются к автоматически задаваемым Id?

Comment: В запросе у вас фигурирует `ProductId`. В определении обеих сущностей такого свойства нет. Вот чес слово, надоело угадывать, что в чём проблема автора вопроса, не видя всего кода.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по вашему описанию, текущий код выглядит примерно так:

```
var product = context.Products.AsNoTracking().First();

var dbItem = new DbItem { Product = product };

context.DbItems.Add(dbItem);

context.SaveChanges();
```

Да, в этом случае возникнет исключение, т. к. сущность `product` не отслеживается контекстом.

Чтобы добавление прошло успешно, нужно либо убрать `AsNoTracking()`, либо присоединить сущность к контексту, тогда она станет отслеживаться.

```
context.Attach(product);

context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Мне как раз и не нужно, чтобы он отлеживал. Мне нужно добавить в таблину DbItem сущность, в которой содержиться сущность Products, но сущность Products не должна пытаться добавиться в соответствующую таблицу Products в БД

Comment: @Anulyev - добавьте в вопрос код, как и что вы пытаетесь сделать.

Comment: добавил в вопрос код

Comment: @Anulyev - как я уже показал в ответе, вы обязаны либо убрать `AsNoTracking`, либо делать `Attach`. Других способов не существует. Можно конечно в обход EF с БД работать, но тогда зачем вообще его было брать? Поймите главное: `product` не будет добавляться в БД, она там уже есть. `Attach` лишь задаст _связь_ между сущностями!

Comment: в любом случае идет обращение к таблице Product и соответственно ошибка  Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' . Насколько я понял Attach используется для обновления сущностей. Я ничего не собираюсь обновлять. Я добовляю нувую запись в DbItem. Сущность Products  в сущности DbItem не должна ничего делать.  Там просто лежат данные из БД

Comment: @Anulyev - `new Dbitem{Id = 1,` - наверняка у вас из-за этого ошибка происходит. Не задавайте Id для DbItem.